# 500 internal error with WSO2 cloud

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0

I've been trying to integrate SAML with WSO2 cloud.
I have some successful experience with other vendors like onelogin, okta, ping one.

But I get a obscure 500 error with wso2.
I get a 500 error with every request I try.

I don't need much - just a SAMLRequest format that will work for WSO2.
For example, now I'm passing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest ID="z9dac5520-d4a4-4da9-b71a-483948c1655c" IssueInstant="2017-04-29T08:40:39.677Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
<saml2p:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"/>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

I defalate, base 64 encode and url encode it.

I tried different variations but nothing works

thanks

Comment: A HTTP500 points to en error on server side. Contact the server's administrator about this.

Comment: I already did. Didn't get a response. I was hoping people that have had luck sending samrequest to wso2 could share an example that worked for them.

Answer (score 1):

The request has no value for the `Issuer` element. Why would any IDP accept a request from an unidentified SP? You need to use a value that identifies the SP and that was previously registered out-of-band with the IDP.

Comment: Added issuer. Still getting 500. can't find any leads as to what is wrong. Any ideas? Thx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sp:AuthnRequest xmlns:sp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceIndex="1" ID="N9ktO4h8k" 
                 IssueInstant="2017-04-30T08:40:39Z" ProviderName="Demo SP" Version="2.0">
    <sa:Issuer xmlns:sa="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://example
    </sa:Issuer>
    <sp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">        
    </sp:NameIDPolicy>
</sp:AuthnRequest>

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do here. Is that enable SAML based authentication via wso2 cloud for one of your application ? If that is the scenario, you need to login to Identity Cloud [1] and configure a service provider as described in [2]. Then only you can send SAML request to Identity Cloud for authentication.

[1] https://identity.cloud.wso2.com
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IdentityCloud/Configuring+SSO+for+Custom+Applications

Once Service provider is configured to accept SAML requests as described in previous links, you can send standard SAML request to Identity Cloud. Sample SAML request is given bellow. Note that AssertionConsumerServiceURL, Destination, Issuer attributes should be changed as relavant for you. Each tenant gets a separate SSO service URL, which is in the format of "https://identity.cloud.wso2.com/identity/t/{TenantDomain}". This will be the value for "Destination" in SAML request.

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://apps.com/travelocity/home.jsp"
                Destination="https://identity.cloud.wso2.com/identity/t/demo1org"
                ForceAuthn="false"
                ID="a9b1b4992f048bb1004677207cc97097a73e47cdaf4ba21360ef8cf38dc76702"
                IsPassive="false"
                IssueInstant="2017-05-02T12:59:45.409Z"
                ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                Version="2.0"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                >
    <samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">wso2App1-wso2org-1.0</samlp:Issuer>
    <saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"
                         Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
                         SPNameQualifier="Issuer"
                         xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                         />
    <saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact"
                                  xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                                  >
            <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have indeed created an account, and an application with assertionUrl and expected issuer, and downloaded the metadata which I parse using openSAML and create a samlRequest.

I took your example SamlRequest and changed issuer and consumerUrl to be relevant. Updated time to current, and I'm still getting 500 when I construct an HTTP request with SAMLRequest (containing the AuthnRequest deflated, 64 base encoded and url encoded) to my wso2 redirection.

The biggest problem is that I'm getting a 500. And couldn't find logs or any lead to how to troubleshoot.